# Is it possible to retrieve which attempt of an SNS message is running on lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a topic at AWS SNS which sends messages to an AWS Lambda function. This function may sometimes fail and depending on which attempt is currently running I need to store some information about the failure. After looking for a while I didn't find any way to do that. Is it possible to retrieve which attempt is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use the [delivery status feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-delivery-status-feature-of-amazon-sns/) and retrieve the attempt number using CloudWatch Events, but apparently SNS always deliver successfully its notifications to Lambda functions.

When a Lambda function fails it retries like explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) and not using delivery polices defined at the SNS topic (because it was delivered successfully).

In this particular case I guess it must be implemented mannually.